# Should I use Collection or List or a regular array for Neo4jClient?

Tags: neo4jclient

I saw some code on StackOverflow of people using Collection<> for the Neo4jClient , but I couldnt find that in any namespace.

Furthermore, I couldnt find any mention of arrays or collections on the Github page. I'm brand new to Neo4jClient so excuse the newbie question (if it is so)

So, can someone tell me how to use an array in Neo4jClient with C# ? Include any namespaces if necessary.

I'm talking about serializing an array (e.g.: string [], List, or Collection<>)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The final step of a Cypher query, `.Results` returns an `IEnumerable`. You can do anything you want with it. Each time you enumerate it, it will run the query against Neo4j.

For example,

```
var users = client.Cypher
    .Match("(user:User)")
    .Return(user => user.As<User>())
    .Results;

foreach (var user in users)   // The query actual runs here
{
}
```

This means that if you enumerated through it twice, you would actually run the query against the database twice:

For example,

```
var users = client.Cypher
    .Match("(user:User)")
    .Return(user => user.As<User>())
    .Results;

foreach (var user in users)   // The query actual runs here
{
}


foreach (var user in users)   // And then it runs again here
{
}
```

Now, that's not usually what you want. You don't want to send the extra call to the database, and you don't want the risk of the data changing.

To get around this, people will often force it to enumerate early by using either `ToArray()` or `ToList()`. These come from `System.Linq`.

For example,

```
var users = client.Cypher
    .Match("(user:User)")
    .Return(user => user.As<User>())
    .Results
    .ToList();   // The query runs here now

foreach (var user in users)   // This just enumerates the in-memory list
{
}


foreach (var user in users)   // This just enumerates the in-memory list
{
}
```

None of this is specific to Neo4jClient: it's just how enumerables work in .NET.

Comment: Thanks, but I was talking about how to make a collection (should I use a List<> or array ?) in a serialized class, and then store and read it back out

Comment: I didnt because my question was different than your answer (which was good). I'm asking how do I DECLARE an array or collection in a class that will be serialized TO neo4j. You're response is talking about how to pull out a collection from neo4j

Comment: ...And then you asked about List<> vs array. And I replied: "Did you try either?" Try defining it as a List<> and see if it works. Try defining it as an array and see if it works. Not everything has to be spelt out for you in programming. Experiment. There is no harm in trying. In this case, you'd have learnt the answer yourself very quickly.